# How to convert data from email to JSON in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to user Power Automate to get data from a new incoming mail and convert it to JSON(to a file) and then work with it in C#. Unfortunately I have never worked with Power Automate. This is my first test, but it doesn't work because of the input, but I did everything according to the instructions here
This is tutorial I've followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62BB3rpe37g

[image: My first attempt]

The inputs of `Split Body Text` is

```
split(body('Html_to_text',outputs('EnterKey')))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Unfortunately your question is off-topic (asking for tutorials/guide lines). Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Since the question is not exactly about C# and JSON, I removed the respective tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after getting the required information, it's actually fairly easy:

You misplaced a bracket. It should be

```
split(body('Html_to_text'),outputs('EnterKey'))
```

within your `Split Body Text` node. `body` takes a single argument.

**On a side note**:

This `EnterKey` node is not really required. You could drop this and replace the `outputs('EnterKey')` with a simple `'\r\n'`.